# Transfer input value

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input, data-transfert-cost

I have a problem with my web site when I use a form with 2 input I want to transfer the value of the 1st input to the 2nd input with minus sign without using the  submit button,knowing that I used the php and js.
Please if any of you have an answer I really need it.

Comment: your question is lacking details... what's the event transferring the data? in real time while typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question right but if so this is what you are looking for using javascript

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setSecondField(value){
document.getElementById("field2").value = value.value+'-';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

   
<input type="text" name="title" id="field1" class="text_box" oninput="setSecondField(this)" />

<input type="text" name="title" id="field2" class="text_box" "/>

</body>
</html>
```